# Set height of multiple containers to the remaining height between two fixed divs

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, mobile-devices

I'm trying to get my site to display nicely on mobile devices. I have a header, fixed to the top, that is 70px height. I have a main menu as the footer, fixed to the bottom with 250px height.

The content in between is multiple pictures one after the other. I would like **each** picture to take up exactly the remaining height between the "header" and the "footer".

I need this to work on mobile devices in general, so I don't want to set the height of the image to a static height (ie: on a 320x480 device I could calculate the height to be 480-70-250 = 160px but I need it to also work on a device that's 360x640px).

Comment: If you have multiple pictures, and each picture takes up ALL the remaining space between header and footer, than your pictures can only be very high and very thin, and can only be displayed left to right. Is this what you intend to do? In any case: Sounds like css flexbox could be your friend: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look up CSS Calc https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/ and also viewport units https://css-tricks.com/the-lengths-of-css/

You could do something like:

```
height: calc(100vh - 70px - 250px)
```

Comment: Perfect. I was worried about cross browser/device compatibility but this seems sufficient. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, set the height of your image to be the height of the window minus the height of the header and footer:

```
$('img').height($(window).height() - 70 - 250);
```

[JSFiddle to demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/wrf3o0q2/)

Comment: with tags html and css for this question, jQuery does not seem like an appropriate solution (and unnecessarily heavy and complex solution for something that may be easily fixable with css only)

Comment: I'm strongly considering jquery, but I would love to solve this using pure css if possible. I hope that jquery is unnecessarily heavy and complex for this solution, but it might turn out to be the best solution for cross browser and cross device compatibility. Thanks for the code @pgruber